# Why reduce $64\bmod{11}$ down to $12\bmod{11}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

This is the problem I am currently working on

Find this value: $(7^3\bmod{23})^2\bmod{11}$

Here's my work:

$$\begin{align*}
&(7^3\bmod{23})^2\bmod{11}\\
&64\bmod{11}=9
\end{align*}$$

This made sense to me because $64 = 11(5) + 9$.

Here is my instructor's answer

> $$\begin{align*}(32^3\bmod{13})^2&\bmod{11}\\(32768\bmod{13})^2&\bmod{11}\\(8)^2&\bmod{11}\\12&\bmod{11}\\&1\end{align*}$$

We both reduced down to $64\bmod{11}$ but I don't understand why she reduced that down to $12\bmod{11}$. It's a lot more intuitive to me to just evaluate $64\bmod{11}$ and get $9$ as the answer. She got 1 as her final answer. Did I miss something?

Comment: Where does $11$ enter into this problem? The question in the picture is different, but your question neither involves $64$ nor $11$.

Comment: First, as @Thomas says, you and the instructor are working different problems. Secondly, the instructor made a mistake: $64\bmod{11}$ is, as you thought, $9$, not $12$.

Comment: Sorry guys typo. 32 Should be 11. I fixed it

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It's 8. I just checked on my calculator.

Comment: Yeah, figured that out by doing it again.

Comment: Why do you think that $7^3\bmod 23=8$?

Comment: Got 25 also. How come it is 1?

Comment: Got 25 for what? @JrAntalan

Comment: The answer before it was mod 32.

Answer (score 0):

Working your problem, 
$$\begin{align}(7^3 \bmod 23)^2 \bmod 11  &\equiv (7\cdot 49 \bmod 23)^2 \bmod 11  \\
&\equiv (7\cdot 3 \bmod 23)^2 \bmod 11  \\
&\equiv (21 \bmod 23)^2 \bmod 11  \\
&\equiv 21^2 \bmod 11  \\
&\equiv 441 \bmod 11  \\
&\equiv 1 \bmod 11  \\
\end{align}$$

Working a version pf your instructor's problem, since I'm almost certain you have changed the second modular base... although probably not the first, since there aren't any other primes $> 8$ that would result in $32^3 \equiv 8$...
$$\begin{align}(32^3 \bmod 13)^2 \bmod 13  &\equiv (6^3 \bmod 13)^2 \bmod 13  \\
&\equiv (36\cdot 6 \bmod 13)^2 \bmod 13 \\
&\equiv (10\cdot 6 \bmod 13)^2 \bmod 13 \\
&\equiv (60 \bmod 13)^2 \bmod 13 \\
&\equiv 8^2 \bmod 13 \\
&\equiv 64 \bmod 13 \\
&\equiv 12 \bmod 13 \\
\end{align}$$